# Spring Security @PreAuthorize- ProviderNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security

I have controller:

```
@RestController
public class CheckPermissionContr {

  @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
  @RequestMapping(value = "/permission", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String checkPermission(@RequestParam("id") UUID id) {
```

When I call it from unit test like:

```
    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @WebAppConfiguration
    @ContextConfiguration("file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml")
    public class CheckPermissionContrTest {

    @SuppressWarnings("SpringJavaAutowiringInspection")
    @Autowired
    protected WebApplicationContext wac;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;


    @Before
    public void init() {

        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        BasicConfigurator.configure();

        this.mockMvc = webAppContextSetup(wac).build();

        final GeneralAuthentication authen = mock(GeneralAuthentication.class);
        user = mock(User.class);

        when(user.getId()).thenReturn(UUID.randomUUID());

        final GrantedAuthority mockAuth = mock(GrantedAuthority.class);
        doReturn("ROLE_USER").when(mockAuth).getAuthority();
        Collection<GrantedAuthority> authority = Collections.singleton(mockAuth);

        doReturn(authority).when(authen).getAuthorities();
        when(authen.getPrincipal()).thenReturn(user);



        final SecurityContext secContext = mock(SecurityContext.class);
        when(secContext.getAuthentication()).thenReturn(authen);
        SecurityContextHolder.setContext(secContext);

        }

    @Test
    public void testCheckPermission() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/permission.json").param("id", id.toString())).andExpect(status().isOk()).andDo(print());
```

When I run test:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderNotFoundException: No AuthenticationProvider found for com.XXXXX.GeneralAuthentication$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$6db1e4cf
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:973)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:170)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:137)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:141)
    at com.XXXXX.CheckPermissionContrTest.testCheckPermission(CheckPermissionContrTest.java:121)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:232)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:175)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:211)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderNotFoundException: No AuthenticationProvider found for com.XXXXX.GeneralAuthentication$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$6db1e4cf
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.config.method.GlobalMethodSecurityBeanDefinitionParser$AuthenticationManagerDelegator.authenticate(GlobalMethodSecurityBeanDefinitionParser.java:433)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.authenticateIfRequired(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:316)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:202)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:60)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:644)
    at com.XXXXX.CheckPermissionContr$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f974fa1c.checkPermission(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHand
```

**But when I replace `@PreAuthorize` with `@Secured("ROLE_USER")` everything go smoothly.**

Contained by `.xml`:

**WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
      <import resource="spring-security.xml"/>
```

Inside **spring-security.xml**

```
<security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>

<security:http use-expressions="true" auto-config="false" entry-point-ref="restEntryPoint">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/*"/>
</security:http>

<bean id="auhProvider" class="com.XXXXX.AuhProvider">
    <constructor-arg name="userRepo" ref="userRepo"/>

</bean>

<security:authentication-manager alias="manager">
    <security:authentication-provider ref="auhProvider">

    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

Additional code:

```
  @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> aClass) {

        return aClass.isAssignableFrom(GeneralAuthentication.class);
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the `supports()` method of your `com.XXXXX.AuhProvider`?

Comment: @zeroflagL I do this now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `com.XXXXX.AuhProvider` supports only objects of the type `GeneralAuthentication.class`. Since you mock `authen` it no longer has this class, but rather `com.XXXXX.GeneralAuthentication$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$6db1e4cf`.

The test in the `support` method must be the other way around:

```
GeneralAuthentication.class.isAssignableFrom(aClass)
```

Which means "is aClass GeneralAuthentication.class or a subtype of it".